# Use Wget to download file from a network request

Tags: http, networking, https, wget

I'm trying to download an mp3 file using wget, but there's no direct link on the page. Clicking the play button spawns a network request that I can navigate to in the browser network requests, but there's no direct link to the mp3 on the page. Is there a way for wget to follow a network request spawned from the page? [example page](https://xray.fm/broadcasts/31579).

> This is what I've tried already:
>   `wget -r https://xray.fm/broadcasts/31579 -A mp3`
>   including making requests to the /31579#play url that comes up when you click the play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that there was an issue with the links present on the page as well as not having the -H flag set for host spanning (the audio was hosted on a separate domain). There was indeed an embedded link to the content I wanted on the page, but because the link didn't end with a '/' it was reading them as files instead of another page to traverse. All of the links I wanted to follow ended in a 5 digit code so I added -A [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] to my wget command and it worked. I tried [0-9]{5} but it wasn't recognizing the links so I expanded it. To restrict the host spanning I added -D xray.fm so it would only span to links that were formatted like X.xray.fm.